# On the definition of the function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

Assume we I have a family of functions $\{f_k\colon k\in\mathbb Z\}$ defined as follows $f_k$ can take any value on $(k,k+1)$ and $f_k=0$ on $\Bbb R\setminus(k,k+1).$ Define $$g=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i.$$ Notice that $g$ is well defined since the functions $f_i$ has disjoint supports, the support of $f$ is $\{x\colon f(x)\neq 0\}.$ Let $g_0=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i.$

My question is:

> Can I rewrite $g$ as folloing ?$$g=g_0\restriction(-\infty,n]\cup f_n\restriction[n,n+1]\cup g_0\restriction [n+1,\infty).$$ Does that correct? Any idea will be appreciated greatly

Comment: What does it mean to take the union of functions and I suppose the "up arrow" means "restricted"? If it means restricted, what does it mean to take the union of functions with different domains?

Comment: @WillM, up arrow means the restricted. note that $f_n$ is $0$ on $\Bbb R\setminus(n,n+1)$

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you **really** are trying to ask. Are you looking at $f$ and $g$ as sets? If so, to prove both sides are equal means to prove $\subset$ and $\supset$. Which part you cannot do and why?

Comment: @WillM. The set-theoretic definition of a function $f:B\to C $ is a special kind of subset of $B\times C$. That is, a function $is$ its graph. So a union of functions is just a union of sets. .. & the up-arrow does mean restricted. Some people just use a vertical line.

Comment: On $(n+1,n+2),$ the RHS function in the last line  is $0$ . But $g(x)= f_{n+1}(x)$ when $x\in  (n+1,n+2)$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I am well aware of that, but I don't know what OP (original poster) is **really asking**. That is why I said, if he is using the set definition of function, then to prove equality he needs to show that each side is subset of the other (just like one would show any two sets are equal). If he means something different, like sum, then the question of "what does it even mean to sum function with different domains mean?" arises. Cheers,

Comment: @WillM. No distinguish has been made between function and its graph.

Comment: @00GB wish the best, if you cannot clarify what confuses you, you probably don't even know what you don't understand. I'll downvote your question.

Comment: @00GB: You need to remove the overlap between the domains: change the middle term to $f_n\upharpoonright(n,n+1)$, and you’re fine.

Comment: @WillM. Thank you. I really have no distinguish between function and its graph . Maybe I will write the function $g$ as union from beginning to avoid confusion.

Comment: @WillM.: It means exactly what it says; all of the OP’s notation is standard.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thank you so much . I thought I did something completely wrong. I am very that have time to see my question.  appreciated it